# Entity Framework Relationships Not Updating

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am having a problem where by updating an entity does not update entities related to it. Here is an example of the code.

```
public class Foo
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Bar> Bars { get; set; }
    public virtual string SomeString { get; set; }
}

public class Bar
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}

public class FooMapping : EntityTypeConfiguration<Foo>
{
    public FooMapping()
    {
        HasKey(f => f.Id);
        HasMany(f => f.Bars);
    }
 }


public class MyDb : DbContext
{
    public IDbSet<Foo> Foos { get; set; }
    public IDbSet<Bar> Bars { get; set; }

    protected override vod OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new FooMapping());
    }
}
```

I receive an update command containg a fooobject from an external application like this:

```
public void Update(Foo foo)
{
    _myDb.Entry(foo).State = EntityState.Modified;
    _myDb.SaveChanges();
}
```

This updates the SomeString value correctly, however the Bar objects are not modified.

I have tried doing the following:

```
public void Update(Foo foo)
{
    foreach(Bar bar in foo.Bars)
    {
        _myDb.Entry(bar).State = EntityState.Modified;
    }

    _myDb.Entry(foo).State = EntityState.Modified;
    _myDb.SaveChanges();
}
```

but this gives a `DbUpdateConcurrencyException`, with the following info

```
Store update, insert, or delete statement affected an unexpected
number of rows (0). 
Entities may have been modified or deleted since entities were loaded. Refresh 
ObjectStateManager entries.
```

How can I get the Bars to update without having to select them from the database?

Thanks

**UPDATE**

I have modified the Bar entity and the mappings as so.

```
public class Bar
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual Foo Foo { get; set; }
}

public class FooMapping : EntityTypeConfiguration<Foo>
{
    public FooMapping()
    {
        HasKey(f => f.Id);
        HasMany(f => f.Bars).WithRequired(b => b.Foo);
    }
 }

public class BarMapping : EntityTypeConfiguration<Foo>
{
    public BarMapping()
    {
        HasKey(b => b.Id);
        HasRequired(b => b.Foo);
    }
 }
```

This doesn't change the anything. I should mention though that even with the first version using `_myDb.Foos.Add(foo)` works correctly (adding all Bars). However it is the update which does not.

Comment: Try adding a relationship from Bar to Foo.

Comment: Note sure if this will help you but I am used to provide both of the navigation properties. What I mean is: try to add the `FooId` and virtual `Foo` to the `Bar` class

Answer (score 0):

You may notice that if `Foo` has new `Bar` items they will be added and (possibly) the existing ones will be nullified. You can try a few things:

Relate Bar to Foo:

```
public class Bar
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public virtual Foo Foo { get; set; }
}

public class FooMapping : EntityTypeConfiguration<Foo>
{
    public FooMapping()
    {
        HasKey(f => f.Id);
        HasMany(f => f.Bars)
            .WithRequired(b => b.Foo); //check this syntax, I'm not entirely sure.
    }
}
```

Try the above. What happened when I had a similar problem was that the "new" Bars where saved and the existing ones where nullified.

The next step you can try is to do a bit of manual deletion when updating:

```
public void Update(Foo foo)
{
    var existing = _myDb.Find(foo.Id);
    foreach(Bar bar in existing.Bars.ToList()) 
    {
        _myDb.Remove(bar);
    }
    existing.Bars.Clear();
    foreach(Bar bar in foo.Bars)
    {
        existing.Bars.Add(bar);
    }
    // map other properties...
    _myDb.SaveChanges();
}
```

Let me know if it works for you.

Comment: The second example will defiantly work, but I was hoping to not have to do a database read to only then update it. No luck with the first method.

Comment: I know... I spent a whole day yesterday trying to find a solution and almost posted an identical question here, then I found solution 2.

Comment: Yeah I have been using solution 2 for a while now but it feels wrong, never mind though. I suppose it's either that or back to using Stored Procedures/Raw SQL.

Comment: The other annoyance of method 2 is that all of the properties need to set explicitly. Because doing this `existing = foo` causes an `InvalidOperationException`